# Setting up router with DSL dialer

Tags: wireless, networking

Ok I have a DSL connection at my home. The ISP has given me a username, a password and the service name. It is a PPPOE connection. I get an ethernet cable from the ISP, which I have directly plugged in my Ubuntu 12.04 machine. I dial using Ubuntu's default network manager DSL connection. Which is basically PPPOECONF. 
So I have a router Linksys WRT54G, on which I have installed DD-WRT. I want to hook up my internet to the wifi, but I need to dial before I can use the internet. Can someone please help me with this. My machine has just one working Ethernet port. What would I have to do, which will enable me to dial via the router(I will need a modem for that), or dial via my system, but when the connection has been dialed via my system, and my system stays on, I must be able to use wifi.

Answer (score 0):

Install wv-dial. First download the wv-dial from net.
Then go to terminal and simple give the following codes. `sudo apt-get update`It will take some time for processing. then to install the wvdial give this code: `sudo apt-get install wv-dial`  this will install the router. then simply restart the computer with the connection on. Starting of ubuntu it will configure the network.

To on the net go to terminal, go to root , then `sudo pon dsl-provider`. it will switch on the connection. To see the log give `sudo plog`. To switch off the connection give `sudo poff`.